# What fish is it?

Tags: ichthyology

I bought this 2 weeks ago, but i forgot to ask the seller, what fish is it.[image: fish]
Currently the size is 1 inch.

Comment: it is one of the 1300 types of cichlids,i do not know what type you have in your tank other than it is definitely a cichlid.

Comment: So, its gonna be 6 in ?

Comment: It looks like albino mouthbrooder for me, actually there is a SE site that is more suited for species identification, it's Biology SE, would you mind to have this question migrated there?

Comment: Really bio site can identify fish? I dont mind though

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit] your post to include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where this creature originated. The location can be an essential clue for identifications. ——— Clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Do you have any clearer photos of it? It's pretty blurry.

Answer (score -2):

An African cichlid. Because it is apparently albino you may not find an exact match.  Start looking under "apistogramma".

Comment: it is a poor picture,over exposed and out of focus so i am not sure it is an albino cichlid.